# What's the best way to connect language relationship of 20k+ product ids?

Tags: php, wordpress, lang

I have 3 languages on a wordpress multisite with 20K+ product id. is there any smarter way to create relationships?
I have all content ids of 3 languages in a CSV file same order.

```
$api = \Inpsyde\MultilingualPress\resolve(\Inpsyde\MultilingualPress\Framework\Api\ContentRelations::class);

$contentIds = [
                    [
                        1 => 42,
                        2 => 123,
                        3 => 321,
                    ],
                    [
                        1 => 42,
                        2 => 123,
                        3 => 321,
                    ],
                    [
                        1 => 42,
                        2 => 123,
                        3 => 321,
                    ]
                ];

foreach ($contentIds as $contentId) {
    $api->createRelationship($contentId, 'post');
}
```